# Image in rviz using code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a launch file that can launch RVIZ with image stream by subscribing to a specific topic. Please guide me through this. I can do it manually right now by clicking on the icon and then subscribing to the topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408283/image-in-rviz-using-code/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I resolved this issue, for future users.

```
    1. Open rviz window.
    2. Go to add and add anything you would like to work with like Motion Planning, Image etc.
    3. Subscribe to the particular topic if needed.
    3. Go to files and save configuration as -> name.rviz 
    4. Open your launch file

 
  <node type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(find package_name)/launch/name.rviz " />
```

---

Originally posted by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) with karma: 61 on 2022-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0